# Error snapshotting jar [sqlite-jdbc-3.20.1.jar]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room

Error:Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'javaPreCompileDebug' property 'annotationProcessorConfiguration' during up-to-date check.

> Error snapshotting jar [sqlite-jdbc-3.20.1.jar]

i am getting this error wheh i used ROOM persistence in my application.Please help.

[Refer this image.I tried lot to know about this error,not able to figure out .Please help me in this,dont know where i am going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgE5D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the reference to the repository into your build.gradle file of your project?

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

}